# How to split columns containing characters and numbers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-quality

In a table I have a column `Building Height` which contains the heights of buildings. Annoyingly the values are entered like this e.g. '18m', '8m' or '8.1m'.

Ideally, it would have the 'm' in the column name and numeric values in the rows but that's not the case. I do not have admin rights to the table in SQL Server.

I need to perform a data quality rule where I need to perform greater than or less than operators on the `Building Height` column.

How do I overcome this obstacle?

Example of the table:

| Building Height | No Storeys |
| --- | --- |
| 8.1m | 3 |
| 13m | 5 |
| 7m | 6 |
| 9.0m | 9 |

Data quality rule to perform:

- If building height is less than 11m, then storeys should be less than 5

I have to find rows that do not fit criteria. Obviously the obstacle is the `Building Height` column containing `m` next to the number.

I've looked into `substring` and `string_split`, but as I do not have admin rights to alter the table I can't really change much, can only query.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `m` and then convert/ast to a numerical data type? Of course, the *real* problem is the design; don't store numerical data as a string and don't have formatting characters as part of its value. Fixing the design should be your *real* priority.

Comment: If the unit is always `m` then you could use something like `CAST(REPLACE(Building_Height, 'm', '') as Int) as BuildingHeight` in a subquery and then use that downstream.

Comment: `that's not the case.` why not? That's the real solution. Anything else just covers up the bad design and guarantees conversion errors. Nothing prevents bad data and only assumptions say that `8.000m` is 8 meters instead of 8 kilometers. Never mind values in feet or inches

Comment: @JNevill sure you zoomed past it but 9.0 (any decimal) will not convert to an int.  With fuzzies, I tend to use money... It is a little more forgiving

Comment: @JohnCappelletti lol. Yeah I zoomed right past it. Thanks for calling it out so OP doesn't try to cast decimals as integers :/

Comment: Thanks everyone, yeah unfortunately the design of the table is out of my hands as  DQ analyst although I have recommended implementing restriction of free text in the front end where users input their values. Anyway, the solution was what most of you suggested, REPLACE() and then TRY_CAST for decimals. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 steps:

1. Remove the `m`
2. Cast result to DECIMAL

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE([Building Height],'m','') step1,
   CAST(REPLACE([Building Height],'m','') as DECIMAL(8,2)) step2,
   [No Storeys]
FROM mytable;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/F9aGKu6y)

Using STRING_SPLIT(), you can do:

```
SELECT 
  m.*,
  CAST(value as DECIMAL(8,3)) as [Height in meters]
FROM mytable m
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Building Height],'m')
WHERE value<>'';
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/n1_xgKyK)

Comment: Considering virtually anything could be in column, I would use try_convert()/try_cast().  They would return NULL if the conversion fails rather than throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM BuildingInfo
WHERE 
    CAST(
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('m', BuildingHeight) > 0 
            THEN LEFT(BuildingHeight, CHARINDEX('m', BuildingHeight) - 1) 
            ELSE BuildingHeight
        END 
    AS FLOAT) < 11 
    AND NoStoreys >= 5;
```

**[See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qOzaHliT)**.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

So used REPLACE () to get rid of 'm' as it is always after the number. Then after the WHERE clause I used TRY_CAST() to convert the string into decimal, otherwise you would get an error in converting string to numeric due to some rows containing decimal values.

Example:

```
WHERE 
  (([No Storeys] >=5) AND (TRY_CAST((REPLACE([Building Height], 'm', '')) AS DECIMAL (22,8)) <11))
```

Code above will locate rows where the data is not consistent with the rule